# What are the support patterns in laravel 4 request beside the wildcard?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Based on the [documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information):

Determining If The Request Path Matches A Pattern

```
if (Request::is('admin/*'))
// What are the support patterns in laravel 4 request beside the wildcard?
{
  //
}
```

I can't seems find a docs that provide more examples than just wildcard.

Comment: i think you can also use regular expression check [here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Str.html#80-106) this is the method which finally handles the call

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul: `preg_quote` is applied to the input pattern - so the only thing you can use is the `*`-wildcard. The rest of the regexp-characters are escaped/quoted and basically "inactive". Maybe OP is more interested in [routing](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing)?

Comment: Guys, I actually want to toggle active menu css

Answer (score 6):

*Guys, I actually want to toggle active menu css*

In that case:

```
{{ (Request::is('home')) ? 'active' : '' }}
```

or

```
{{ (Request::segment(1) == 'home') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

or

```
{{ (Request::path() == 'home/special') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

or make your own

```
{{ (preg_match('whatever you want here', Request::path()) ? 'active' : '') }}
```

Edit: Looking at the Request::is() function in the Laravel core:

```
/**
     * Determine if the current request URI matches a pattern.
     *
     * @param  string  $pattern
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is($pattern)
    {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $pattern)
        {
            if (str_is($pattern, $this->path()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

So you could actually pass in any 'pattern' and it will match it against str_is()

Comment: imagine I have multiple sub-level menu beneath, the comparison will be pretty messy

Comment: Oh, this is my current hack. But I would like to fully utilise the `is` method, is there a way?

Comment: the bug has this comment https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/1481, `Fix Str::is to not handle haystack as a regex.`, I guess is not possible for regex?

Comment: Correct - but this commit has some tests which show some options: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/a294377094eef1bbc91dd213201a7581222b1969

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" {{ (Request::is('url*')) ? 'class=active' : '' }}>Link</ a>
```

Try this:

```
Request::is('url*')
Request::is('url/*')
```

Example:

```
<a href="#" {{ (Request::is('products*')) ? 'class=active' : '' }}>Link</ a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" {{ (Request::is('products')) ? 'class=active' : '' }}>Link</ a>

<a href="#" {{ (Request::is('products/*')) ? 'class=active' : '' }}>Link< /a>
```